# I have an array of objects, and I need to find the person that is associated with a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a bunch of information about different users stored in the object, and I need to be able to find a user using that user's ID number. Here's the object:

```
var users = [
      { "name":"Tim" , "status":"Offline", "userGUID":"012" }, 
      { "name":"Bill" , "status":"Online", "userGUID":"324" },
      { "name":"Stephen" , "status":"Online", "userGUID":"777" },
      ];
```

So, if I know the user id is 324 (and each id will be unique), how do I search through this object and find out the name of the user?

Would it be better if the object was arranged like this?

```
var users = {
      "Tim":{"status":"Offline", "userGUID":"012" }, 
      "Bill":{"status":"Online", "userGUID":"324" },
      "Stephen":{"status":"Online", "userGUID":"777" },
      };
```

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Are the id's in sorted (increasing) order, or is that just a coincidence in your question? If they are, then is a significant difference between the two, since arrays have order and objects do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an array:

```
var users = [
  { "name":"Tim" , "status":"Offline", "userGUID":"012" }, 
  { "name":"Bill" , "status":"Online", "userGUID":"324" },
  { "name":"Stephen" , "status":"Online", "userGUID":"777" },
];
```

All the keys are numbers and the members are objects, so to access Tim's ID, the syntax would be `users[0].userGUID`; which would be tedious to look up a user by their ID.

The second is an object containing several objects:

```
var users = {
  "Tim":{"status":"Offline", "userGUID":"012" }, 
  "Bill":{"status":"Online", "userGUID":"324" },
  "Stephen":{"status":"Online", "userGUID":"777" },
};
```

Here, to access Tim's ID, the syntax would be `users.Tim.userGUID`.  Since the GUIDs will be unique, I'd recommend you name the objects after their ID's:

```
var users = {
  "012":{status:"Offline", name: "Tim" }, 
  // etc...
  };
```

That way, `users["012"].name` is `"Tim"`.  Otherwise, you'll have to loop through every object, looking for that ID.

Comment: I quoted "012". without quotes it gets octalified and becomes the key "10"

Comment: Ok great, thank you very much. This is basically what I was looking for, and I think making the GUID the name won't mess anything else up, and it seems a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

For your first snippet of JSON:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (user.userGUID === "324") {
        var name = user.name;
        // do something with name...
        break;
    }
}
```

As far as your question, however you arrange your object contents is up to you. It depends a great deal on what you want to do with it. The easiest way to think about it is that collections of objects should be arrays, while the properties of those objects should be a type other than array.

Comment: I would note that this is only valid for the array example and maybe add `break` once the ID is found.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I added that clarification.